# How to Split in C#?

Tags: c#

I am using code for splitting :

```
columnVal = val.Contains(":") ? val.Split(':')[1] : val;
```

Example #2 Approval Level: Formulator  I am getting result  Formulator
As per expected ...But
Now having issue when date and time is there
Example #2 Approval Date: 11/18/2015 3:53:22 PM
Result 11/18/2015 3
I am looking for whole string 11/18/2015 3:53:22 PM
What to do in this ? Please help me

Answer (score 4):

You need [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx) of `string.Split`, where you can specify the maximum number of substrings to return:

```
columnVal = val.Contains(":") ? val.Split(new [] {':'}, 2)[1] : val;
```

So it will stop splitting after the first `:`.

Comment: That is not the correct parameter, it should be something like `new [] { ':' }` or `":".ToCharArray()`. Although I never noticed a second parameter existed on split, nice find.

Comment: Oh yeah, oops. Fixing.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the string split once, rather than at every possible symbol match, use [`string.SubString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`string.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var index = val.IndexOf(':') + 1;
columnVal = (index < val.Length && index >= 0)
    ? val.Substring(index)
    : val;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the first occurrence of `:` and take the rest of the string using [`string.Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) after that in order to get your desired output.

```
columnVal = val.Contains(":") ? val.Substring(val.IndexOf(':') + 1).Trim() : val;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 string parseTarget = "Example #2 Approval Date: 11/18/2015 3:53:22 PM"

 int  colonPosition = parseTarget.IndexOf(":");

 if (colonPosition == -1)
 {
      throw new Exception("Missing Delimeter");
 }

 string Value = parseTarget.Substring(colonPosition + 1, parseTarget.Length - colonPosition - 1);

 console.WriteLine(Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using String.Split / String.Contains, I would advise using `Regex.Split`. It's more flexible in that you can specify a maximum amount of positions and different splitting parameters. On top of that it's shorter and more readable than the other answers provided, imo. See [Regex documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98awefz7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Code snippet for you:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(":");
string[] result = rgx.Split(val, 1);
string date = result[1];
```

Alternatively, you can replace the last line with the following snippet if there will **ALWAYS** be a split:

```
string date = rgx.Split(val, 1)[1];
```